# Fasten single line of code for div resize

Tags: javascript, css

I have this one single line of code I wanted to improve. My main concern is the execution and rendering speed of it. Even though I am happy with its speed, could it be improved?

```
document.getElementById('my-webpart').style.height = 
(document.documentElement.clientHeight - 80) + 'px';
```

The reason I didn't ad any variable is to make it robust but I'm not sure if it even matters.

Comment: Are you sure you have exhausted all possible ways to accomplish this using just CSS and no JavaScript? Height control in CSS is admittedly tricky, but it might be possible.

Comment: What's the context of your code? [If your question contains stub code, then there are significant pieces of the core functionality missing, and we need you to fill in the details. Excerpts of large projects are fine, but if you have omitted too much, then reviewers are left imagining how your program works.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3649/52915)

Comment: @Mast Concept is to resize my webpart in SharePoint 2013 based on document's height as soon as possible, I used to use jQuery document.ready and calculate height of sharepoint divs and then set height on my elements which was slow and clients could see components resizing, so i decided to add this code to last of my webpart (an asp.net page) to size my components as soon as possible

Comment: @200_success , sorry but i didn't get you, how can i get browser's height using CSS ?

Comment: See [How to set div height 100% minus nPx](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1192783/1157100), which might be relevant.

Comment: I have rolled back the Rev 2 → 1. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how many times this is executed. If you execute this multiple times inside a resize function, setting a global variable that stores your element will speed up your code since it does not have to look up the variable every time. So if you are using `window.resize`, this would be a tad bit faster:

```
var myWebPart = document.getElementById('my-webpart');
var docElement = document.documentElement
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    myWebPart.style.height = (docElement.clientHeight - 80) + 'px';
}, false);
```

However, the difference we are talking about is negligible. I always tend to look at this as `document.getElementById()` being a *function* and functions **need** execution time, so if you already have the answer (the element) and you are going to use it multiple times, then it might be best to store the answer in a variable. If, however, you only use it once, it's best to *not* store it in a variable as you are increasing the memory usage for something that does not need to be stored, as well as executing a tiny bit of code to allow for this memory to be used. Every bit slows down, but we are really talking minimal changes here.

### Update

I'm adding my two pence concerning the height issue you are mentioning. It is easier to do with CSS, but I would avoid using `box-sizing`, instead using something like the below as it works as expected across browsers while having a fallback for older browsers:

```
/* Define a height for older browsers */
height: 80%; 
/* Use calc to get the simulated border-box-sizing height / ignored by old browsers */
height: calc(100% - 80px); 
/* Define a padding for older browsers */
padding-bottom: 20%; 
/* Use calc to get the simulated border-box-sizing padding / ignored by old browsers */
padding-bottom: calc(80px);
```

I know `box-sizing` is popular for this, but I think `calc` solved our problem to begin with, and it makes box behaviour more predictable as they will always work in the same fashion.

Comment: very nice, thanks but sorry i am not able to +vote, you are right I am planning to resize it several time, haven't got there yet, but it helps, going to test it now

Comment: Ha thats fine :) I thought you could on your own question, but either way glad to help :)

Comment: i think your code is missing where it should be resizing it before window resize event triggers, I updated my code in question to be more within context, thanks :)

Comment: @user2262511 Note you should be able to mark his answer as accepted. However, it might be beneficial to wait at least a day before doing so.

Comment: Please note the lowercase `resize`, also, this was an example more than anything else. I think the actual event is `onresize`, but it would be better not to overwrite that function and add an `eventlistener` for this, but that was not the concern of the question. I'll amend the answer though. If you want to know more about a good way to use that event, check MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize (because of computational expense it might be better to combine it with `requestAnimationFrame`)

Answer (score 3):

At the moment of a resize, you trigger this A LOT! to you it's just 1 movement, but the browser triggers the function per pixel (worst case). You might be looking for [dethrottle/debounce](https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls):

```
window.onresize = function(event){debounce(function (event) {
        document.getElementById('my-webpart').style.height = (document.documentElement.clientHeight - 80) + 'px';
}, 50)};
```

This triggers your code every 50ms. You can increate this number for better performance, decrease it for smoother animation.

---

You can do this with css, which is a lot easier. The trick is to [change the box sizing](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/):

```css
#example {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background: pink;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
#my-webpart {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 80px;

  background: green; /* FOR DEMO */
  width: 50%; /* FOR DEMO */
  color: #FFF; /* FOR DEMO */
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
  <div id="my-webpart">
    Hi there! Use your console to check my actual height, which in this example is 120px;
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since he defined it as a sharepoint site you can assume older browsers in the network will access it. I avoid using `box-sizing` for this reason, but you can emulate it with calc and an appropriate fallback: `height: 80%; padding-bottom: 20%; height: calc(100% - 80px); padding-bottom: calc(80px);`, this will display semi-correctly on older browsers while falling 'forward' perfectly fine on newer ones. Best of both worlds.

Comment: But IE8 won't do the calc. It'll fix a bit more, but still not everything.

Comment: Scratch this, IE8 has bloody `border-box` support. Don't know why I have bene telling myself it hasn't for a long time now. Maybe because I don't like how unpredictable the behaviour is when using it, but thats just me.